# Db2 xmlcast specification

Tags: db2, db2-400

`Select xmlcast('<case_id>123</case_id><checknumb>2345</checknumb>' as XML)`

This query returns

```
&lt;case_id;gt;123&lt;/case_id
&lt;checknumb&gt;2345&lt;/checknumb
```

How to get 
`<case_id>123</case_id<checknumb>2345</checknumb>`

Why its coming like this when casting into xml.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to cast a string literal `'<case_id>123</case_id><checknumb>2345</checknumb>'` as an XML *string*, not an XML *document*. XML strings cannot contain angle brackets inside them, because these symbols have special meaning for XML parsers, so the angle brackets are converted to entities.

If what you really want is to convert your literal `'<case_id>123</case_id><checknumb>2345</checknumb>'` to an XML *document*, you need to make it a valid XML document first (by adding the root element) and then use `XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '<root><case_id>123</case_id><checknumb>2345</checknumb></root>')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to produce an `XML sequence`, then you should use [XMLCONCAT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzscaxmlconcat.htm) scalar function, and not try to cast a string constant to the XML type.

```
VALUES XMLCONCAT(XMLELEMENT(NAME "case_id", 123), XMLELEMENT(NAME "checknumb", 2345));
```

If you need to produce an `XML document`, then you should use the following:

```
VALUES XMLELEMENT(NAME "doc", XMLCONCAT(XMLELEMENT(NAME "case_id", 123), XMLELEMENT(NAME "checknumb", 2345)));
```